# Stuck between navigationController and segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have 3 `ViewControllers`, *VC1*, *VC2* and *VC3*. *VC1* and *2* is using navigation Controller bars with a back button. *VC3* is using a `segue` back to *VC2*.

When I `segue` back from *VC3* to *VC2*, the "back"-button on the navbar takes me back to *VC3* and not *VC1*. So I'm stuck in that loop and I wonder how to break off and make it so that the "back"-button takes me where it is supposed to, to *VC1*.

Comment: Segues work only in the context of pushing and popping VCs onto a navigation controller, so what do you mean when you say that VC3 isn't in the nav controller, but has a segue back to VC2?

Comment: Use segue for going forward, not going back. System will manage the back-action for you automatically.

Comment: Oh so segue might not be the way to go? The reason i use segue is because i want to move data between VC3 and VC2, can i do that without segue?

Comment: For this you can use either the delegate-pattern or unwind-segues (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)